# Java - InstanceAlreadyExistsException with Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am doing multithreading with Mongodb and sometimes I have this message when running my script :

```
8 juil. 2011 14:13:59 com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder get
ATTENTION: jmx registration error: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.mongodb:type=ConnectionPool,host=180.20.0.20,port=27017,instance=1593488603 continuing...
```

I checked on Mongodb and saw no traces of my connection...

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also opening multiple connections of mongo db in multiple threads one after another for some benchmarking and getting the same error.

Now I have resolved the error by sleeping for 200 milliseconds before starting another thread and create new mongo connection